# How to know that data is updated (i.e. data deleted, modified or inserted) in mysql table, so that update json object in java

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, json

In my application I want to render data in JSP using JSON which I store in a file, so that the data can be rendered on screen faster (saving the time to hit db and get result every time user search records).

The data on screen can come from multiple tables (using joins).

How will I know that data in the tables are changed so that I will have to rebuild the JSON object once again by firing the query on the DB and then storing the output in JSON obj. to a file. So that updated output is displayed on screen.

Comment: So you want to build your own 'database' (file system) and need a synchronization mechanism? Sure you need that kind of 'optimization'?

Comment: Where's the file held? If it's on the server, what makes you think that'll be appreciably quicker than just re-querying the database? Have you measured the response times?

Comment: Yes the file will be on the Application server. And yes many queries (which are optimized) that fire on screen typically takes 2-3 secs to give output .. plus other network response time to be added .. moreover i currently use sturts which typically reload whole page on any action, which also take time .. if i change this architecture to show records from json object using ajax then reloading time will also get saved ..

Comment: Well, if you're using AJAX and Struts to access your JSON file, you can use AJAX and Struts to access your database. Building a synchronisation layer between your database and the JSON object is either going to be hit-or-miss, or extremely complicated. Probably the easiest way of doing it would be to maintain a date_time_last_updated column on each of the important tables in your database and querying that before you decide whether to return the cached data from the JSON file, or re-query the database. But it'll get very ugly, very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I can see this options:

- Delete the cached JSON file after every write operation to the DB. Depending on your application this can get vers tedious.
- Store the JSON file as a blob in the DB and use tirggers/store procdedures to delete the blob after a write operation.